# display success message after form submit ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a simple html form with modal and I am saving data with ajax method. Now, I want to display a success message for a few seconds. I tried many ways from stackoverflow, but did not work. Please someone help me.Here is my form and ajax code.
HTML:

```
      <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>New
                </button>
        <div id="add" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <form id="save" method="post" enctype="" name="myForm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <strong>Add+</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>Student ID:</label>
                                <select name="student_id" id="student_id" onChange="names('student_id')" onkeyup="names('student_id')">
                                    <option value="">select id</option>                                                     
                                        <?php 
                                        include 'connect.php';
                                        $sqlst="Select * from student_info";
                                              $queryst=mysqli_query($connect,$sqlst);
                                              while($rowst=mysqli_fetch_array($queryst)){
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $rowst[1]?>"><?php echo $rowst[1]?>
                                        </option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                                </td>                               
                                <td>
                                    <label>Date:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="att_date" id="att_date" class="selector" onChange="names('att_date')" onkeyup="names('att_date')"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="student_id_error" style="color:#FF0000"></td>
                                <td id="att_date_error" style="color:#FF0000"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label>Sign In Time:</label><input type="text" name="sign_in" id="sign_in" onChange="names('sign_in')" onkeyup="names('sign_in')"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label>Sign Out Time:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="sign_out" id="sign_out" onChange="names('sign_out')" onkeyup="names('sign_out')" disabled/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">
                        Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
<div id="info" style="display: none;">
 Data Successfully inserted!
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var base_url="http://localhost/school/";
 $('#save').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var student_id=$('#student_id').val();
    var att_date=$.trim($('#att_date').val());
    var sign_in=$.trim($('#sign_in').val());
    var note=$.trim($('#note').val());
    if(student_id===''||att_date===''||sign_in===''){
        if(student_id==''){
            $('#student_id_error').html('Please enter Student ID');
            $('#student_id').css("border-color","red");
        }
        if(att_date==''){
            $('#att_date_error').html('Please enter attendance date');
            $('#att_date').css("border-color","red");
        }
        if(sign_in==''){
            $('#sign_in_error').html('Please enter signIn time');
            $('#sign_in').css("border-color","red");
        }
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url:base_url+'student_att_insert.php',
            method:'post',
            data:new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(){
                
  $("#info").show();
  $("#info").delay(5000).fadeOut(); // Will hide after 5 seconds
            //window.location.assign('student_att_index.php')
            }
        })
    };
 });
 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to show us what you tried, and describe what the problems with that were.

Comment: Are you sure that is there not a z.index problem? You are in an open modal and trying to open a div. Is this div in position:absolute and with z-index?

Comment: In this div nothing position:absolute and with z-index.Now what should I do?

Comment: Now I am using :                                                                   div.succesDiv
{   
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
} And It's working. In the success function, last I used window.location that's why It is redirecting before 5seconds(but when not using window.location it's remain 5seconds)But I need to show success message for 5seconds after redirection.I place my success message div in modal body before table.Where should I place message div and What should be z-index value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a div in your HTML with an id like :

```
<div id="info" style="display: none;">
 Your text
</div>
```

And in your JS code add :

```
$("#info").show();
$("#info").delay(5000).fadeOut(); // Will hide after 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But, it's not working.

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan well you have to make sure your JS work fine ! I didn't check ur JS

Comment: My JS working fine. After add a div in HTML I wrote your code like this:$.ajax({
            url:base_url+'student_att_insert.php',
            method:'post',
            data:new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(){                
$("#info").show();
$("#info").delay(5000).fadeOut(); // Will hide after 5 seconds              
                window.location.assign('student_att_index.php');
           
            }
        })

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan and what happened ?

Comment: Nothing.But data inserted.

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan maybe remove this part :window.location.assign('student_att_index.php');

Comment: Same as before.Data inserted but did not show message and modal not hiding.

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan can you please update your question with edited html and js codes pls ?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.Now I updated my question with edited html and js codes as you said.

Comment: I tested ur code without the Ajax part and it work correctly ! Do you use any jQuery library ? And are you sure you get success message back ?

Comment: Yes,I am using many others jQuery library. Now It's working better after success: function(){
   $("#info").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.assign('student_att_index.php')
            }, 3000);                  Thank you sir for your valuable time.

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan no problem, so ur problem resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

On success show your msg in html.
After 5sec it will load 'student_att_index.php'

```
    success: function() {
            //display success message for a few seconds
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.assign('student_att_index.php')
            }, 5000);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.After submit my form, It stay only for 5seconds and redirect to 'student_att_index.php' but,did not show anything else (ex. alert box/message)

Comment: for that you will have to add code for ex. alert("Success"); just add before window.location.assign('student_att_index.php')

Comment: I added alert("Success") before window.location.assign('student_att_index.php').Now It is showing alert box after 5seconds and have to click ok to redirect 'student_att_index.php'

Comment: I recommend you to show success msg in html instead of alert box like this $("#info").show(); and as we have setTimeout it will redirect after 5sec

Comment: Thank you. Now It's working fine after success: function(){
   $("#info").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.assign('student_att_index.php')
            }, 5000);